# get an error trying to install google chrome

Tags: apt, google-chrome

I'm getting an error after installing Google Chrome.

When I try to do `sudo apt-get update` I get this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Bad header line [IP: 37.29.1.44 80]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add this line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   sudo echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. download and install key

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A040830F7FAC5991
   ```
3. update the repo

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```